# Get array of strings from tsv with d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am trying to get an array of strings from a tsv file using d3.  My aim is to define a global variable that is equal to all of the strings contained in the column `label` in my tsv fie.

When I try the method below - all I see is `NaN` on the page.  Using d3, how does one fetch all of the strings contained in a tsv column and define it as an array?  For example

`labels = ["label1", "label2", label2",...]`

```
  d3.tsv("newdata.tsv", function(error, data)
{
   var labels=0;
   data.forEach(function(d)
   {
     d.label = +d.label;
     labels = labels + d.label;
   })
   document.write(labels);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are not creating your array properly. You should declare it like `var labels = []`
2. You are not adding the values to your array correctly. You should use `.push`
3. You do not need the `+` operator since you're only dealing with strings. The `+` operator coerces a value to a number.

Working code below:

```
d3.tsv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/3305937/raw/a5be7c5fd55c4fa0ca8a400cb68d658a40989966/data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  var labels = [];
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x = d.x;
    labels.push(d.x);
  })
  console.log(labels);
});
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cpdafLpf/

Comment: This is working but I just get an array of `NaN` .  I double checked the file and that column definitely contains strings.

Comment: Is there are reason the values are being read as `NaN` instead of strings?

Comment: @the_darkside apologies, forgot to remove the `+` operator which we don't need in this case.

Comment: console.log works except when I try to use `labels` again in another part of the script - it is not defined.  how could you make it a global variable?

Comment: @the_darkside you can just move the array declaration outside. Check here - https://jsfiddle.net/fuxnfzat/